# Efficient way of Searching in JSON Object in java

Tags: java, json, keyset

I have a list of JSON Objects as:
`[{"name":"abc","id":"123"},{"name":"xyz","id":"345"}..]` and a set of parameters like `{"abc","def","xyz"}.` I want to check whether the second set of parameters contains value that are not in name field of JSON Object in first array.

**The algorithm I followed is:**

```
Boolean flag = false;
   for{name : nameSet} {
     if(jsonObject.get("name")!=name{
       flag = true;
     }
   }

   if(flag){
     System.out.print("not matched");
   }
```

Are there any efficient way of doing it? Please suggest?

Comment: What is the implementation of `jsonObject.get()`?

Comment: @Cargeh Didnt get what you are asking, can you explain

Comment: whether this could be optimized requires understanding of how `jsonObject.get()` works (the algorithm). If this is pseudo code, then the question is unlikely to be answered. If this is a library function, please provide the name of the library

Comment: @Cargeh I have used org.json.simple.JSONObject in java

Comment: First, you should start by comparing `String` correctly. `jsonObject.get("name")!=name` will not work. Then, simply break the iteration when you get flag at true.

Comment: `JSONObject ` inside has `has(String name)` method. Isn't it enough?

Comment: I would use JsonPath unless there was a measured issue with performance

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking each element with every element of Json array. You'll be needing an additional for loop for same.

**Edit** : Added the Json data to a key `data`. Refer the `String json`.

```
   Boolean found = false, flag = false;
   String json = "{ \"data\": [{"name":"abc","id":"123"},{"name":"xyz","id":"345"}]}"
   JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
   JSONObject getData = object.getJSONArray("data");

   for{name : nameSet} {
     found = false;
     for(int i = 0; i < getData.size(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = getData.getJSONObject(i);
        if(jsonObject.get("name").equals(name)){
          found= true;
          break;
        }
     }
     if(!found){
         flag = true;
         break;
     }
   }

   if(flag){
     System.out.print("not matched");
   }
```